# Can we skip execution of certain maven plugins via new maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a `main-project` which has multiple plugins in its pom.xml that perform different tasks like `compile` , `running test` , `validation` .

I want to create a new maven-plugin , which will (based on a condition , if true) skip the execution of rest of the plugins.

In short if that condition is true , I don't want to `compile` , `install dependencies` or `run tests` for my project , I want to directly show build as successful. Is that possible .

I am trying to keep this new plugin execution at the time of Initialize as it needs to be run initially before anything else is executed ->

```
@Mojo(name = "buildCache",defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.INITIALIZE)
public class BuildCacheMojo extends AbstractMojo {

}
```

Comment: First question: Why do you like to skip those plugins? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise  I will check if source files , dependencies and versions and compiler configs are not changed at all , I will pick cache of the previous build , instead of building again.

Comment: Many plugins have a short circuit configuration, e.g. the compile target of the compiler plugin has `<skipMain>`. You could set build variables from your plugin (e.g. set `skip.compile` if sources haven't changed) and use it in the pom (e.g. `<skipMain>${skip.compile}</skipMain>`).

Comment: Why do you have a version control system? What is the real problem here?

Comment: Why building if nothing has change? Don't you use a version control system?

Comment: So I'm trying to explore `build cache`. (similar to - try googling/youtube build cache by gradle).
We have a CI system , where builds are run on regular basis whenever a new commit is pushed. Main project has 10 other maven modules , not all of them are  necessarily changed every time , only a couple , so every time main project is build again and again , I want to build only modules that are changed or have dependencies on the modules changed.

Comment: Than you will not succeed with using skipping of modules. You have to analyse the dependencies between the modules and check based on the version control what has change. That can only be achieved by using an extension. (Basic idea: https://github.com/khmarbaise/incremental-module-builder) but using Gradle enterprise cache works without skipping modules or plugins. Apart from that how long is the overall build time (`mvn clean package`).. Do you use most recent versions of all plugins and more imporant do you use most recent versions of Maven?

Comment: That's the plan, to analyze the dependencies and build required modules which are interdependent.I'll check your extension.

Couldn't find much details about their product apart from that gradle hashes the input and compares in consecutive builds ,so you're saying gradle enterprise cache works differently and does not skip modules ? hm...trying to figure out the design how It can be done.

Overall build time (`mvn clean install`) takes ~70min.

I believe not so recent , `compiler-plugin` is `3.8.1` , `shade-plugin` - `3.2.4` , enforcer-plugin - `1.4.1` ,dependency-plugin - `3.1.2`